# get data from a webpage with VBA

Tags: html, vba, web-scraping

I would like to extract from a webpage some data with VBA.
This is an invoicing program and I am trying to access the first line of data which is the product description
I am not an expert is these matters, but I looked into the html code being one of the fields of data and it looks like this:

```html
    <td class="">
       <div class="UITextbox length length_maximum-255" data-tag="product_code" data-ui-widget="UITextbox"><span class="field"><input autocomplete="off" id="sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_product_code" name="sales_invoice[line_items_attributes][0][product_code]" readonly="readonly" size="30" type="text" /></span></div>
    </td>
    <td class="">
       <div class="UITextbox presence length length_maximum-200" data-tag="description" data-ui-widget="UITextbox"><span class="field"><input autocomplete="off" id="sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description" name="sales_invoice[line_items_attributes][0][description]" size="30" type="text" /></span></div>
    </td>
    <td class="hidden numeric">
       <div class="UIHiddenField" data-tag="item_id" data-ui-widget="UIHiddenField"><input autocomplete="off" id="sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_item_id" label="false" name="sales_invoice[line_items_attributes][0][item_id]" type="hidden" /></div>
    </td>
    <td class="numeric">
       <div class="UIDecimal presence numericality numericality_greater_than_or_equal_to-0 ensurenotgreaterthanmaxnumber ensurenotgreaterthanmaxnumber_maximum-99999999" data-tag="quantity" data-ui-widget="UIDecimal"><span class="field"><input class="hidden" name="sales_invoice[line_items_attributes][0][quantity]" type="hidden" value="0.00" /><input autocomplete="off" class="visible" data-scale="2" id="sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_quantity" name="" size="30" type="text" value="0,00" /></span></div>
    </td>
    <td class="">
       <div class="UIDropdown" data-tag="unit_type" data-ui-widget="UIDropdown">
       <span class="field"><select autocomplete="off" id="sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_unit_type" name="sales_invoice[line_items_attributes][0][unit_type]">
```

I tried this so far with no results:

```vb
    Dim desc as string
          
    desc = ie.Document.getElementsByClassName("UITextbox presence length length_maximum-200")(0).innerText
```

The following code has no errors, but no value either.

Comment: The code isn't working for me.

Comment: can you include the url please or more of the html. There is no innerText value in the above. What is the expected return value?

Comment: i have just added some more html code from the . I was looking for the second block of code to get the description elemt data. the link for the page is :https://app.pt.sageone.com/facturacao/invoicing/sales_invoices/new , but there is a password to enter so I guess it will not help. thanks

Comment: what is the description please you are expecting back?

Answer (score 0):

There isnt any Text in the Div you are looking at:

```
<div class="UITextbox presence length length_maximum-200" data-tag="description" data-ui-widget="UITextbox">
    <span class="field">
        <input autocomplete="off" id="sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description" name="sales_invoice[line_items_attributes][0][description]" size="30" type="text" />
    </span>
</div>
```

But the Input has an ID that you can use to get the value from

```
desc = ie.Document.getElementByID("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description").value
```

Comment: ie.Document.getElementByID("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description").value , passes the value of the description field on first row, but can I get the second row aswell ? or only one unique value?thanks

Comment: I have not looked at the site, it requires a login/an account. Based on the html and code you provided, you can get the description with my answer. I have no idea what you mean with "Second row", you meant he quantity?

Comment: With second row I mean that  the value I am getting with ie.Document.getElementByID("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description").value, is the value of  the first child, so how would I get the next sibiling ?

Comment: Have you tried "sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_quantity" and "sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_unit_type"

Comment: I did try those and it works fine,  but still i am not able to get the other sibiling values and I assume that getElementbyID is not the solution. thanks

Comment: Did you try the hidden inputs? Again, i can not see the website due to login, maybe javascript unhides those and thats what you are talking about, the hidden inputs that become available.

Comment: -would you mind looking into the the webpage. I can send you login and password, after all there is no sensitive information in it , this is just a Demo version of the program. should I post the log in information here ?

Comment: I tried to start a chat but i think you need over 20 rep. I can log in if you provide the details. Make sure to explain exactly the fields you are trying to get the value from.

Comment: login : cpampas@hotmail.com   pass: Cc351351    the web page : https://app.pt.sageone.com/facturacao/invoicing/sales_invoices/2185778
in the last invoice issued, we have  line test 1 ; 5 ; unidades;345;0;0;normal;1725, and another line test 2 ;21,unidades;111,0;0;normal;2331
and finaly the last line
my purpose is do add data to add new invoices, wich is here : https://app.pt.sageone.com/facturacao/invoicing/sales_invoices/new. Is it posible to create a new invoice with 3 lines as in the previous example ?

Comment: Based on the code of the website, as soon as you enter values on the fields, a second line will show up and should let you enter data. However, there is a problem, the ID for the <input> fields are generated randomly, you will not be able to use the ID as easy. There is a random number that is user for each line. It's not impossible, but it will be harder than just using the ID. You may need to loop some tags (input), verify for id name, enter data. If with VBA the second line is not being added automatically after entering data, you may need to use "fireEvent".

Comment: you were right I need a fireEvent in order to a new line to be added, do you know why the fire event try wont add  a new line ?
      IE.Document.getElementById("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description").Value ="LINE 1 DESCRIPTION"
      IE.Document.getElementById("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description").focus
       IE.Document.getElementById("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_0_description").FireEvent ("onChange")
       ' 
      IE.Document.getElementById("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_1_description").Value ="LINE 2 DESCRIPTION"

Comment: The inputs may be tied to a different event like, onkeypress or onkeydown and stuff, but you can try the onChange on the Select dropdown, that should also trigger the new Line.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this is not the most eficient way, but I couldnt find any other way, so I just used sendkeys to simulate the keypress that adds a new record, since I could not have the fire event to work.
Thanks for your help Ricardo

```
      IE.Document.getElementById("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes       _0_description").Value ="LINE 1 DESCRIPTION" 

     SendKeys "-"
     SendKeys "{ENTER}"

   IE.Document.getElementById("sales_invoice_line_items_attributes_1_description").Value ="LINE 2 DESCRIPTION"
```